# Copy data from single columns on different sheets into columns on one sheet in order of the sheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy-paste

I think I am on the right path as far as my overall code structure. I can't figure out some of my variables.

I copy columns of data to the last row on 9 different sheets and then paste that data into the Summary Sheet (the ActiveSheet) in range B6:J, while keeping the data in order by columns.

"A" is the Time and Date (TnD) column that I take from the first sheet.
The Offset(-2,0) for TnD is trying to remove the last two rows of Time/Date as they are repeating data for when logging was stopped.
B3 and C3 are the cells the first data point is recorded on the sheets being copied.
A6 and C6 are the cells I want to paste the data into.

I get my first error

> '424 object required'

```vb
Set LastRow = DatSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)
```

This is the section.

```vb
'Copy data to Condition sheet
DatShs = Array("303_0", "304", "305", "306", "307", "308", "309", "310", "311_0")
Set DatSh = DatShs.Name.Select
**Set LastRow = DatSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)**
Set TnD = DatSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0)'''

For Each DatSh In DatShs
    Sheets(DatSh).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.DatSh.Range("C3" & LastRow).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Paste
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select
    If DatSh("303_0") Then
        DatSh.Range("B3" & TnD, "C3" & LastRow).Copy 
        ActiveSheet.Range("A6").Paste
    End If
Next DatSh
```

This is the whole sub. It starts by multiselect and pulling in the worksheets with the data from other workbooks.

```vb
Sub GetSheets_GetData()
 Dim OpenThisFile As Variant
 Dim SelectedBook As Workbook
 Dim FileCnt As Byte
 Dim DatSh As Worksheet
 Dim DatShs As Variant
 Dim LastRow As Range
 Dim TnD As Range
 Dim NxtColm As Range
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'adds hobo data to workbook
  OpenThisFile = Application.GetOpenFilename _
 (Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Select Data Files to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
 
 If IsArray(OpenThisFile) Then
    For FileCnt = 1 To UBound(OpenThisFile)
    Set SelectedBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=OpenThisFile(FileCnt))
    SelectedBook.Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    SelectedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Next FileCnt
  End If 'isarray
'Copy data to Condition sheet
 DatShs = Array("303_0", "304", "305", "306", "307", "308", "309", "310", "311_0")
 Set DatSh = DatShs.Name.Select
 Set LastRow = DatSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)
 Set TnD = DatSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0)
 
 For Each DatSh In DatShs
  Sheets(DatSh).Select
  ActiveWorkbook.DatSh.Range("C3" & LastRow).Copy
  ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Paste
  ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select
  If DatSh("303_0") Then
   DatSh.Range("B3" & TnD, "C3" & LastRow).Copy
   ActiveSheet.Range("A6").Paste
  End If
 Next DatSh

Sheets("311_0").Range("B" & DatSh.Cells(DatSh.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
   ActiveSheet.Range("A6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share the whole thing i.e. from `Sub...` to `...End Sub`? Is the code in the workbook containing these worksheets? Is the worksheet that you're copying to, the *"Summary Sheet"*, in the same workbook, and what is its (tab) name? Could you more accurately describe what you are trying to do: include clarifications about `.Offset(-2, 0)`, `C3`, `C6`, `B3`, `A6` and `E0303_0`. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72311753/edit) at any time.

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and updated my post. let me know if it needs any more clarification.

Comment: If you want to select the whole sheets name in your defined array, I think `Set DatSh = DatShs.Name.Select` should be `sheets(DatShs).select` ---> this will select all the sheets name you mentioned in DatShs array. To get the last row of column C in each sheet name in the array, I think your `Set LastRow` should be inside the loop `For Each DatSh In sheets(DatShs)` then the next line `Set LastRow = DatSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)`

Comment: If you are sure that the last row of column C on each sheet name mentioned in the array is all the same, then maybe you can have the LastRow variable as string, and before the loop you put `LastRow = Sheets(DatShs(1)).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Address`. Inside the loop `ActiveWorkbook.DatSh.Range("C3:" & LastRow).Copy`

Comment: And in the loop, your `If DatSh("303_0") Then` I think it should be `If DatSh.Name = "303_0" Then`

Comment: Okay, you are making some good sense to me. I will give these a try and let you know what i find! Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: This certainly seemed to clean up some of the code. But Its still getting errors at the same spot. Thanks for your input!